# Dynamic keys in Pydantic v2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

Trying to use pydantic to model a json file like this:

```
{
    "people": {
        "Jack": {"age": 32, "postcode": 1223},
        "Robert": {"age": 23, "postcode":2354},
        "Sarah": {"age": 55, "postcode":5673}
    }
}
```

I also have a list of acceptable names I like to enforce:

```
accepted_names = ["Jack", "Robert", "Sarah", "Alex"]
```

I have tried to use `__root__:[Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]` but this is deprecated in version 2 and the error message says I should use `RootModel` instead but the pydantic documentation is not clear on how to do this.

What I have so far:

```
import json 
from pydantic import BaseModel, RootModel, conint
from typing import Dict

class PersonModel(BaseModel):
    age: conint(ge=0)
    postcode: conint(ge=1000, le=9999)

class MyModel(RootModel):
    root:Dict[str, PersonModel]

    def validate_root(cls, v):
       acceptable_names =  ["Jack", "Robert", "Sarah", "Alex"]
       if v not in acceptable_names:
            raise ValueError(f"Names should be one of {', '.join(acceptable_names)}")
       return v
        
class ParentModel(BaseModel):
     people: MyModel

file = "scratch/test.json"
with open(file, "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

mymodel = ParentModel(**data)
```

But the way it works now is `mymodel.people.root['Jack']` whereas I want `mymodel.people.Jack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### My Answer

I think you can modify the method `__getattr__` for `RootModel` instead of calling `.root`.

```py
    def __getattr__(self, item: str):
        return self.root.__getitem__(item)
```

### My Example

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, RootModel, conint, ConfigDict
from typing import Dict


data = {
    "people": {
        "Jack": {"age": 32, "postcode": 1223},
        "Robert": {"age": 23, "postcode": 2354},
        "Sarah": {"age": 55, "postcode": 5673},
    }
}

class PersonModel(BaseModel):
    age: conint(ge=0)
    postcode: conint(ge=1000, le=9999)

class ParentModel(BaseModel):
    class MyModel(RootModel[Dict[str, PersonModel]]):
        def __getattr__(self, item: str):
            return self.root.__getitem__(item)

    people: MyModel


mymodel = ParentModel.model_validate(data)
print(mymodel.people)
# > root={'Jack': PersonModel(age=32, postcode=1223), 'Robert': PersonModel(age=23, postcode=2354), 'Sarah': PersonModel(age=55, postcode=5673)}
print(mymodel.people.Jack)
# > age=32 postcode=1223
```

Comment: I edited your answer and removed my approach from it, so that others can get straight to the solution.